# how to use multiple EditText in textwatcher for gst calculation

Tags: android, textwatcher

I have multiple(3) EditTexts in my activity .

I want to do an action for  when the text in them changes. Do I need to have 7 different TextWatchers or is there a way to use the same one for or and do some kind of switch?
I tried something like this.I'm new now so don't know much
Please explain me in detail

```
    public void sellTextViewCalInt(){
    s_mrp_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s_mrp_value);
    s_rate_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s_rate_value);
    s_discount_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s_discount_value);
    s_taxable_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s_taxable_value);
    s_tax_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s_tax_value);
    s_price_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s_price_value);
    s_total_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s_total_value);
}


   public void sellTabelCalculateView() {

    final EditText text_sale_rate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.item_sale_rate);
    final EditText text_sale_discount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.item_sale_discount);
    final EditText text_sale_tax = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.item_sale_tax);

    sellTextViewCalInt();

    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String rate = text_sale_rate.getText().toString();
            String discount = text_sale_discount.getText().toString();
            String tax = text_sale_tax.getText().toString();

            int sellRateInNo = Integer.valueOf(rate);   // String to Integer
            int sellDisInNo = Integer.valueOf(discount);   // String to Integer
            int sellTaxInNo = Integer.valueOf(tax);   // String to Integer

            s_rate_value.setText(item_sale_rate.getText().toString()); // at is String
            s_discount_value.setText(text_sale_discount.getText().toString());// at is String

            int taxableInNo = sellRateInNo - sellDisInNo;// calculation
            s_taxable_value.setText(String.valueOf(taxableInNo)); // Integer to String

            int taxInNo = (taxableInNo * sellTaxInNo) / 100 ; // calculation
            s_tax_value.setText(String.valueOf(taxInNo)); // Integer to String

            int priceInNo = taxableInNo + taxInNo ;  // calculation
            s_price_value.setText(String.valueOf(priceInNo)); // Integer to String

            int mrp = sellRateInNo + taxInNo; // calculation
            s_mrp_value.setText(String.valueOf(mrp)); // Integer to String
        }
    };

    text_sale_rate.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    text_sale_discount.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    text_sale_tax.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

    s_mrp_value.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    s_rate_value.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    s_discount_value.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    s_taxable_value.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    s_tax_value.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    s_price_value.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    s_total_value.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

}
```

If I do something like this, then the calculation where and how can I not understand this?

```
 private final TextWatcher rateValue  = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        s_rate_value.setText(item_sale_rate.getText());
        int rateInNo = new Integer(s_rate_value.getText().toString());

    }
};

private final TextWatcher discountValue  = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        s_discount_value.setText(item_sale_discount.getText());
        int discountInNo = new Integer(s_discount_value.getText().toString());
    }
};

private final TextWatcher taxValue  = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        s_tax_value.setText(item_sale_tax.getText());
        int taxInNo = new Integer(s_tax_value.getText().toString());
    }
};
```

Comment: afterTextChanged: give logic if else
`if s == text_sale_rate.getEditableText() etc`

Comment: I'm new now so don't know much Please explain me in detail  . Please give me a complete example and please do great understanding

Answer (score 0):

try this
activity or fragment should implement TextWatcher

text_sale_rate.addTextChangedListener(this);

text_sale_discount.addTextChangedListener(this);

text_sale_tax.addTextChangedListener(this);

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
    if (s== text_sale_rate.getEditableText() ) {
      //what should you do when text_sale change
    } else if (s == text_sale_discount.getEditableText()) {
      //what then
    } else {
      //another logic 
    }
}
```

Comment: this shown error as   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xUnWb2wTKAFTOYh3v1yFo14RQAaIUi5G/view?usp=sharing

Comment: try getEditableText() instead of getEditable()

Comment: this  getEditableText() and getEditable() both are showing error